# remove elemento do Full calendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

tenho um full calendar que permite que eu utilize os eventos em outros elementos fora do calendário, no entanto, eu gostaria que os eventos padrões que vem no calendário como por exemplo o prev, next e today pudessem removidos do calendário para que eu possar utilizar a suas respectivas funcionalidade nos seguintes elementos taskElementPrev,taskElementNext,taskElementToday.

Obs: abaixo a uma foto com os botões do calendário que devem ser excluídos do painel do calendário.

Então, no eventClick eu tenho essa função:

```
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek'
            },
            defaultView: 'month',
            viewRender: function (view) {
                var title = view.title;
                $(".taskElementCalendar").html(title);
                var prev = view.prev;
                $(".taskElementPrev").html(prev);
                var next = view.next;
                $(".taskElementPrev").html(next);
                var today = view.today;
                $(".taskElementPrev").html(today);
            }});
```

Comment: Ficou bem confusa a sua pergunta. Podia dar uma revisada na pergunta para tentar ficar mais clara.

Comment: E achei mesmo que ficou, na verdade o problema é completo mesmo, irei revisa

Comment: Pelo que entendi, essa função serve apenas para construir o calendário, não tem nenhum "event click" nela.